# Installing Windows 7 via USB gives "CD/DVD drive device driver is missing" error

Tags: windows-7, usb, installation, uefi

Apparently a lot of people have had this problem but I've tried all their solutions and came up with nothing.

I'm trying to install Windows 7 64-bit SP1 via USB on an ADATA SP550 SSD with an ASUS H110M-A motherboard. I used the Rufus utility to "burn" the iso onto my usb drive with a GPT partition scheme for UEFI (although I've tried the other partition scheme options in Rufus).

When I boot the USB on the computer I'm trying to install Windows 7 on it loads the files, allows me to select my language etc., then gives me the option to click "Install Now". I do that and it says "Setup is starting". After a few seconds I get a window that pops up saying "A required CD/DVD drive device driver is missing. If you have a driver floppy disk, CD, DVD, or USB flash drive, please insert now."

I don't have a DVD drive at all (let alone one connected to the machine). I've tried a whole bunch of solutions that I've found online such as unplugging and then plugging the USB drive into another port (USB 3.0 or 2.0), attempting legacy boot, trying to find SATA drivers for the motherboard and attempting to load those. Nothing has worked. One thing I wasn't able to do is to is confirm the selection of AHCI in the UEFI. I can't for the life of me find it. Although I don't think that's the issue because I can install Windows 10 or any number of Linux distros just fine on that machine.

I'm sort of at my wits end here. I guess the only thing realistically left to do is just to go out and buy a CD/DVD drive and attempt the install through that.